# Selecting all NULL values in attribute table using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, select-by-attribute

I want to select ALL my null values in an attribute table of a feature class, not just the values in a single field.

What is the valid SQL statement that could get me all the null values?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Without knowing what your data looks like, the general syntax you need to insert into the select by attributes window is:

```
[FIELD_1] IS NULL OR [FIELD_2] IS NULL OR [FIELD_3] IS NULL
```

and so on for as many fields as you have to work with. For reference the full query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE_NAME] WHERE [FIELD_1] IS NULL OR [FIELD_2] IS NULL OR [FIELD_3] IS NULL
```